# iOS Keychain disable sharing data

Tags: ios, keychain

It seems to be a big feature to share data between different Apps through the iOS Keychain, but how can I avoid the sharing between apps? I can't find anything for that case in the Apple documentation.

I know that the access-group and therefore the access of the keychain for an app is defined through the provisioning profile with the parameter *keychain-access-groups*.

```
<key>Entitlements</key>
<dict>
    <key>application-identifier</key>
            ...
    <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
    <array>
        <string>XXXXXXXXXX.*</string>
    </array>
</dict>
```

After Apple redesigned their developer-page it is not more possible to create different App-Prefix-Ids where defines the keychain-access-groups. I hope someone can give me a hint, how to prevent the sharing of the keychain for different apps with the same code base.

Additional Note:
It is not possible to save the data with different keys.

Update:
I found an attribute that set on runtime the keychain-access-group *kSecAttrAccessGroup* I think this should help to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstood what share means here, which is you can opt to share with different apps produced by you and accepted by Apple. Arbitrary apps cannot access your app's keychain data.

Comment: But it seems to be, three apps with different bundle-identifiers but the same app-id-prefix return the same content from the keychain. On all apps we use the same key but different servicenames!

Comment: But didn't you have to do something to make this work - check something, or add a '*' prefix? I know you can share between a family of apps, but it was suppose to require active selection on your part to make it happen. Sorry but I have my self not looked into this, was just aware of the capbabilty.